# RPM verification error what is mean by P

Tags: linux, rpm, verify

I have created an RPM and that installs successfully. After installing, when I tried to verify the RPM with --verify command I am getting an error on executable file X it returns as

```
...P /location/to/file/X
```

I don't know what is mean P. The file has a special capability to listen the ports set by setcap. Can you please tell me what is mean by P? I have searched through Google but did't get any luck. Thanks in advance

Comment: When the quality is this low, I was surprised to find out it wasn't a review test question after moderating...

Comment: Run `man rpm` and search for `--verify`.

Comment: Strange, the [documentation](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-verify-output.html) itself does not describe any `P` flag. The last flag on the line should be `T` instead. Upvoting because this question may be more interesting than it looks.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You are looking at old documentation. `P` is a newer flag that that (often outdated) book didn't cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained (albeit briefly) in the rpm [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm):

rpm {-V|--verify} [select-options] [verify-options]

> Verifying a package compares information about the installed files in the package with information about the files taken from the package metadata stored in the rpm database. Among other things, verifying compares the size, digest, permissions, type, owner and group of each file. Any discrepancies are displayed. Files that were not installed from the package, for example, documentation files excluded on installation using the "--excludedocs" option, will be silently ignored.
>
> The format of the output is a string of 8 characters, a possible attribute marker:
>
> ....
>
> from the package header, followed by the file name. Each of the 8 characters denotes the result of a comparison of attribute(s) of the file to the value of those attribute(s) recorded in the database. A single "." (period) means the test passed, while a single "?" (question mark) indicates the test could not be performed (e.g. file permissions prevent reading). Otherwise, the (mnemonically emBoldened) character denotes failure of the corresponding --verify test:
>
> ....
>
> P caPabilities differ

So the capability of the file in question differs on disk from the capabilities of the file as listed in the rpm files section. How it differs is up to you to find out (and possibly fix).

Comment: thanks Etan Reisner the file bapabilites is changed on spec  file after its installed fixed it thanks.